# convert a dict field to **list** for use in **enumarate**

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have an object which can be either JSON or dict (I dont know which one will happen):

**type 1** : `q = {result : {"info" : "info"}}`

or

**type 2** : `q = {result : [{"info" : "info"} , {"info" : "info"}]}`

I want to iterate a procees for each result.
for type2

---

```
for i,x in enumerate((q["result"])):
```

work good but have problem with type1 
and

```
for i in q :
```

good for both of them but have **lack of index** in type2 becuse need index of results
is there any code to support both of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a prelim check to see what `q['result']` holds, and wrap a list around it if need be -

```
if isinstance(q['result'], dict):
    q['result'] = [q['result']]
```

Now, `enumerate` should work regardless. This works out to be pretty cheap since you're only moving references around.

Comment: prelim check? :D explain pls